# Linux Perl - Convertion of Hex Value to Decimal

Tags: linux, perl, hex, decimal

I am developing a script that convert collected HEX ( I don't know the Bit format of them) values to Decimal Values.

One of the example is the hex value: fef306da
If I convert it, I receive 4277339866.

Website where I found the expected value (Decimal from signed 2's complement:):
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

Do you guys have a solution how can I convert hex fef306da to decimal -17627430.
Note: I get wrong value conversion when I convert hex that have (-)negative sign when decimal.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [pack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack) and use modifiers for unsigned and signed values.

```
my $hex_value = "fef306da";
my $output_num = unpack('l', pack('L', hex($hex_value)));
print $output_num; ## -17627430
```

Perform a test on each hex value to determine if it is a 16bit or 32bit value.
Then use the correct modifier with pack for long or short values.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooo much for explaining! Both of you saved my life. I wish I know that before. It just happened that it is my first time messing with different hex to decimal conversion.. ^_^ And by the way.. Your $output_num must be your $num? XD Thanks again!

Comment: sorted it - glad it helped you. pack is valuable tool.

Answer (score 3):

it seems that you expect your decimal to be 32bit signed integer, but HEX($n) returns a 64bit one
so you may try repack it

```
perl -e 'print unpack "l", pack "L", hex( "fef306da" )'
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mike! I appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you interested in binary conversion then check following code (`fef306da` is 32bit number)

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $input   = 'fef306da';
my $hex     = hex($input);
my $dec;

if( $hex & 0x80000000 ) {
   $dec = -1 * ((~$hex & 0x7fffffff)+1);
} else {
   $dec = $data;
}

say $dec;
```

Output

```
-17627430
```

Tip: [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Tip: Use better var names. `$hex` doesn't contain anything hex. Also, `-1 * ((~$num & 0x7fffffff)+1)` can be simplified to `0x1_0000_0000 - $num`

Comment: @ikegami -- well I agree that it should be `$raw` but as derivative coming from hex value would be easier to understand  for people who is inexperienced in binary math. I need _imprint_ in my brain `0x1_0000_0000-$num` as alternative -- now looking at _binary operation_ it become very obvious, somehow it did not come to me why there present **+1**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pack`

```perl
my $hex = "fef306da";
my $num = hex($hex);
$num = unpack("l", pack("L", $num));
say $num;  # -17627430
```

or

```perl
my $hex = "fef306da";
$hex = substr("00000000$hex", -8);   # Pad to 8 chars
my $num = unpack("l>", pack("H8", $hex));
say $num;  # -17627430
```

But simple arithmetic will do.

```perl
my $hex = "fef306da";
my $num = hex($hex);
$num -= 0x1_0000_0000 if $num >= 0x8000_0000;
say $num;  # -17627430
```